# Dealing with google calendar api php documentation

Tags: php, command-line, google-api

I need help on the google calendar documentation. I am a beginner at this and I really would appreciate even the slightest of advice. First of all, I am trying to download google apis client library for php and am following the instructions on the website below.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

This website first of all states to download the newest file of google api php client which is in the form of a tar.gz file. Unfortunately, I accidentally set to open the file to permanently open in notepad which I don't desire and I need help fixing it.

Now the main problem is the next step which is: Extract the library from the archive and copy the google-api-php-client directory to your project root.

First of all I cannot extract the file because the file is saved as notepad and I don't know of a way of how to change it. Secondly, there are several steps that I cannot perform on command prompt which the google api php wanted me to do. The code is separated in lines below:

curl "http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-php-client-0.6.5.tar.gz" -O

tar -xvf  google-api-php-client-0.6.5.tar.gz

cd google-api-php-client/examples/

I tried to do this code in command prompt and unfortunately end up with curl is not an internal command or external command as well as tar is not an internal command and external command. Am I supposed to download curl.exe or some other extracting software because I was searching up on the internet and have yet to find a concrete answer? Or is there something else wrong that I am doing?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what operating system you are using.  I'm going to assume some flavor of windows?  Cmd window error for 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

You can find window tools that will unpack a .tar file, eg. www.7-zip.org

You can also download a Curl tool for windows, something like http://curl.haxx.se/download.html     (Cmd is not always the best tool for command line interpreter in Windows.. Windows PowerShell is probably a better tool to use... but now you are pushing the limits on trying to learn too many new things at the same time.)

On the other hand, I'm not sure I'd go there if I were you.  If you need to look at Google's documentation for calendar its available online.  I recommend you learn one or two new skills at a time. Until you are ready for the full Google API, why not just use their online stuff for Calendar. See http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples#Calendar_API
You will find samples and documentation there in a pretty easy to use format.

It sounds like your registry opens up notepad whenever a .tar file is found. You can un-register that thru windows explorer.  Different techniques depending on which flavor of windows you have.

The really awesome thing is when you just beginning, you get lots of chances to learn new stuff.  Take it slow, have fun.  Just got to stuff it into your brain... Good luck with it.

Zip